# OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak

Tags: linux-mint, openvpn

Linux Mint 21

Success install openvpn.

```
OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022



openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
built on: Mon Aug 15 08:08:28 2022 UTC
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Now want to connect to remote setup via openvpn.

```
sudo openvpn Leo.ovpn
```

but get error:

```
2022-08-15 09:29:10 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2022-08-15 09:29:10 --cipher is not set. Previous OpenVPN version defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers.
2022-08-15 09:29:10 WARNING: file 'client.key' is group or others accessible
2022-08-15 09:29:10 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
2022-08-15 09:29:10 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2022-08-15 09:29:10 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2022-08-15 09:29:10 OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
2022-08-15 09:29:10 Cannot load certificate file client.crt
2022-08-15 09:29:10 Exiting due to fatal error
```

P.S. I check folder. Exist files: client.crt and ca.crt

```
sudo openssl x509 -text -in ca.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            d5:a0:93:fa:24:35:4d:95
```

...

Comment: Not really specific to Linux Mint, but to OpenVPN and the OpenSSL version it has been linked with.

Comment: Agree. Better to omit the Tag Linux-mint.

Answer (score 27):

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

just as said above, add this

```
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

to your **vpn client config(not openssl.cnf)**, mine looks like this(example):

```
client
tls-client
ca vpnname/ca.crt
cert vpnname/user.crt
key vpnname/user.key
tls-crypt vpnname/myvpn.tlsauth
proto udp
remote 1.1.1.1 1194 udp
dev tun
topology subnet
pull
user nobody
group nogroup
script-security 2
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
#up /etc/openvpn/vpnname/up.sh
#down /etc/openvpn/vpnname/down.sh
```

UPDATE about NetworkManager

As people said in the comments, for NetworkManager openvpn you need to add `tls-cipher=DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0`

inside your `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/name-of-your-openvpn.nmconnection`

into `[vpn]` section

and restart `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: Note that in order for this to be picked up, you need to restart NetworkManager: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Comment: add `tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"` to the ovpn file.

Comment: In case you need to set this for one particular connection managed by NetworkManager: The configuration file is located at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` and the NetworkManager specific syntax is `tls-cipher=DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0`.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is in the error messages (`error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak`). OpenSSL refuses to use the CA certificate because certain parameters are considered insecure nowadays. This could be caused by the certificate using MD5 or SHA1 for signing.

You should regenerate your CA and certificates with secure hash algorithms for the signature, as your currently used hash algorithms are not considered secure anymore.

There is a workaround available by adding the following to your `openssl.cnf`:

```
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

Another workaround is available since [OpenVPN 2.6.0](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/v2.6.0/Changes.rst):

> #### OpenSSL 3.0 support
>
> OpenSSL 3.0 has been added. Most of OpenSSL 3.0
> changes are not user visible but improve general compatibility with
> OpenSSL 3.0. `--tls-cert-profile insecure` has been added to allow
> selecting the lowest OpenSSL security level (not recommended, use only
> if you must). OpenSSL 3.0 no longer supports the Blowfish (and other
> deprecated) algorithm by default and the new option `--providers` allows
> loading the legacy provider to renable these algorithms.

Comment: This "tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"" not help

Comment: Can you add to the question a sanitized version of `openssl x509 -text -in ca.crt`?

Comment: That is extremely sanitized, and not very useful :) . Please post the output with just identifying marks removed (subject, issuer, that sort of stuff).

Comment: I fixed the problem. See my answer

Comment: @mtak I interpret this the same as you, but in my case I get `Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption` and since it is a self-signed CA, there is no certificate chain with weaker algos either. Mysterious. However, the _user_ cert uses SHA1 in my case (`Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption`).

Comment: Not only is this the fullest answer (including advice to regenerate the certs if possible - although note that the CA is irrelevant and doesn't need to be regenerated even if it's using MD5), but it's also the first answer to have the solution. I'm not sure why the other answer is higher voted.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - only the signature on the (non-CA) cert is relevant. Since the CA is self-signed and separately distributed to/trusted by all systems, its signature does not matter.

Comment: @DimeCadmium `md` in the error message refers to "message digest" and isn't limited to the algorithms having that acronym in their name, e.g. MD5. It includes SHA-1, SHA-2 etc. When I read an error message such as `error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak`, however, I expect that `ca` to have a meaning. I only figured that the user certificate was meant by inspecting the certificates, obviously. But I still wonder what `ca` means in the context of the error message. Of course the user certificate needn't be issued by a (self-signed or not) CA either, I reckon, but typically it _would be_.

Comment: @DimeCadmium there's one flaw in this answer, which I noticed just now: it claims this is about ciphers being deemed insecure. That's simply wrong. It's not about ciphers at all. It's about cryptographic hash algorithms -- or in alternative lingo "message digests" -- not about the key ciphers.

Comment: I did not mean "even if it's using MD5" to exclude the possibility of the error message also applying to other digests than MD5, rather just using the "most broken" as an example. -- I imagine that "ca md" means "the MD signed by the CA", but I do not know. One thing OpenSSL is not known for, IMHO, is obvious error messages :) -- If the user cert isn't signed by a (trusted) CA, then you will either need to disable cert validation or pin it. In this case the sig algorithm on the cert doesn't *technically* matter, though I don't know how OpenSSL treats it.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
Linux Mint 21
OpenVPN 2.5.5 , Mar 22 2022
OpenSSL 3.0.2 , 15 Mar 2022
```

I fix the problem:

I install openvpn ver. 2.4.7 and now no error.

```
OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Aug 15 2022
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022, LZO 2.10

OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can use deb from oficial ubuntu LTS https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/openvpn_2.4.7-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html/ mirrow https://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openvpn/

Answer (score 1):

Note that although changing `ovpn` configuration is a working workaround it might not be the best solution. SHA1 has a low level of security even with long keys (SHA-1 is considered to have less then 80 *bits of security* for digital signatures). See: [Recommendation for Key Management, NIST Special Publication 800-57 Part 1, NIST, May 2020](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r5.pdf).

### Modify CA/certificate

What you should do is change `openssl.cnf` you use to sign and generate certificates.

```ini
[CA_default]
# ...
default_md = sha256
# ...

[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
```

Generating a certificate with above settings should be indicated in the crt/pem file like so:

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
[...]
RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

All this might a bit of work depending of how many certificates you have.

### Workaround

So as a workaround you can add security level of 0 in `*.ovpn` (on the client side):

```
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

Note that SECLEVEL=0 means any algorithm is allowed ([security levels info](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html)).

This workaround might be fine depending on how are you using the certificates (e.g. for local tests or public facing stuff) and how big of a target you are... and what other layers of security do you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in the article
[Ubuntu 22.04 OpenSSL error fixing](https://blogiestools.com/ubuntu-22-04-openssl-error-fixing/):

> Ubuntu and Xubuntu 22.04 moved to  OpenSSL 3.0. This is causing errors (0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak) with Wifi and other internet connections. This is because OpenSSL 3.0 considers MD5 and  SHA1 hash Algorithms used on old CA certificates invalid.

Although the article is for Ubuntu,
it probably also applies to the latest Linux Mint.

This article proposes the following solutions:

> **Solution 1**: If you are using Wi-Fi or a VPN and you are getting the error, then the immediate solution is to renew your key pairs to
> be compatible with OpenSSL 3. This is because OpenSSL 3 which is used
> by default in Ubuntu 22.04 does not accept SHA1 algorithm. Learn more
> about OpenSSL 3.0.
>
> **Solution 2**: Install OpenSSL 3 . Here is a guide on how to install OpenSSL 3 on Ubuntu 22.04.
>
> **Solution 3**: If you are facing a problem with SSH, then make sure that you have selectively enabled it as it is disabled by default in
> OpenSSH.
>
> **NOTE**: Third-party packages that use libssl1.1 will also need to be upgraded to libssl3.

Comment: I success installed OpenSSL 3.0 but it not help

Comment: You need to recreate the certificate - it's too weak. Do not use these old hash algorithms.

Comment: It's impossible because certificate generate by admin. I can't access for this procedure

Comment: If you are obliged to use it, then you need to configure  OpenSSL. (Downgrading to an older version of Linux is never a good idea.) See the [Providers section](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Providers) of the OpenSSL wiki for an example config. You need to load the legacy provider.

Comment: I fixed the problem. See my answer